# WPF Need to find a way to identify TypeOf on custom Page class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nullreferenceexception, typeof

I have a Window class called MainWindow, and in its constructor, builds a default Page class I call, MonitorPage that populates my window with this page at launch. In my MainWindow, I have three buttons that act as page tabs or menu buttons that upon clicking them will create an instance of a different Page class, in my case I have three unique pages. MonitorPage, DataBasePage, HelpPage. In my MainWindow, I want to "grey-out" the tab button when that corresponding page is up. I have a method in MainWindow called, PageState(), that tries to identify which page is currently up to enable or disable and grey out the tabs. My problem is that I get a NullReferenceException in my method at the first IF check.

**The Error I'm Getting:**

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content.get returned null.
```

**C#:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace EyeInTheSky
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml + backend code for FileSystemWatcher project
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region Fields
        private FileSystemWatcher _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        private ObservableCollection<string[]> _eventList = new ObservableCollection<string[]>();
        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Main.Content = new MonitorPage(ref _watcher, ref _eventList);
            PageState();
        }

        private void PageState()
        {
            if (Main.Content.GetType() == typeof(MonitorPage))
            {
                Menu_MonitorButton.IsEnabled = false;
                Menu_MonitorButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(88, 88, 95));
                Menu_DataBaseButton.IsEnabled = true;
                Menu_HelpButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else if (Main.GetType() == typeof(DataBasePage))
            {
                Menu_MonitorButton.IsEnabled = true;
                Menu_DataBaseButton.IsEnabled = false;
                Menu_DataBaseButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(88, 88, 95));
                Menu_HelpButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Menu_MonitorButton.IsEnabled = true;
                Menu_DataBaseButton.IsEnabled = true;
                Menu_HelpButton.IsEnabled = false;
                Menu_HelpButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(88, 88, 95));
            }
        }

        private void Menu_MonitorButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PageState();
            Main.Content = new MonitorPage(ref _watcher, ref _eventList);
        }

        private void MenuStrip_DataBaseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PageState();
            Main.Content = new DataBasePage(ref _eventList);
        }

        private void MenuStrip_HelpButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PageState();
            Main.Content = new HelpPage();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Name="Home" x:Class="EyeInTheSky.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EyeInTheSky"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Eye In The Sky - Windows File System Watcher" Height="450" Width="1105" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" Background="#FF39393E" Foreground="#FFE4E4E4" FontFamily="Roboto">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="27*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="394*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="240*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="859*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Frame x:Name="Main" Height="421" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Panel.ZIndex="10000">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Menu" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Background="#FF4E4E53">
                <Button x:Name="Menu_MonitorButton" Content="Monitor" Width="80" Click="Menu_MonitorButton_Click" Background="#FF4E4E53" BorderBrush="#FF585858" Foreground="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="Menu_DataBaseButton" Content="Data Base" Width="80" Click="MenuStrip_DataBaseButton_Click" Background="#FF4E4E53" BorderBrush="#FF585858" Foreground="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="Menu_HelpButton" Content="About" Width="80" Click="MenuStrip_HelpButton_Click" Background="#FF4E4E53" BorderBrush="#FF585858" Foreground="LightGray" Padding="0,1,1,1" BorderThickness="1,0,2,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is Main.Content `null` ?

Comment: Not after the MainWindow constructor, Main.Content should be assigned a Page object, MonitorPage.

Comment: Odd, you're right Tony. Main.Content is null when the PageState() method is called. I don't understand why Main.Content's...content is not saved when the method is called. Here is the debugger info on Main.

    [Property]      [Value]    [Source]    [Style Value]    [Declared Type]
    `Content null     Local     <not set>    System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl`

Comment: Also give a look at Page `KeepAlive` property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I took a look Tony and placed KeepAlive in my pages, but still the same issue. The issue is coming from the Main.Content assignment. Using it to launch a page works perfectly fine, but the Main.Content value is kept null even though the page is opening from it.

Comment: You are setting the Content property to a MonitorPage and then you are checking if it is set to a MonitorPage immediately afterwards? What's the point? Please provide a MCVE of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The information you have provided here doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear, I found a solution and will be updating this soon as I can. But, what I was trying to do was open a Page called MonitorPage within a Frame's content property called, Main. So that's why it's Main.Content = new MonitorPage(...). Then, in my PageState() method I want to check to see which page is currently assigned to Main.Content as I can assign one of three different pages to Main depending on the menu item button clicked.

Comment: When/if PageState() method matches/tries to match a corresponding page to Main's content by typeof, I adjust the background color and disbale and enable the menu item buttons to explicitly show which menu we're on. An aesthetic adjustment only. Like I said, I'll be posting my solution here soon, but TLDR, I use Uri's.